# Best way to send HTTP response code in PHP

Tags: php

From reading the php spec and other questions on Stack Overflow, I can see three ways of sending an HTTP response code from PHP:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
           ^      ^     ^
           A      B     C

header(" ", false, 404);
        ^     ^     ^
        C     D     B

http_response_code(404);
                    ^
                    B

A: Defines HTTP header
B: Response code
C: Message
D: To replace previous header or not
```

What is the difference between these and which one is the best to use? Is my understanding of the parameters correct?

Thanks,

Tugzrida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question about what is the difference, I found [this comment](http://php.net/http_response_code#116880) in the PHP docs (thanks Steven):

> `http_response_code` is basically a shorthand way of writing a http
>   status header, with the added bonus that PHP will work out a suitable
>   Reason Phrase to provide by matching your response code to one of the
>   values in an enumeration it maintains within
>   php-src/main/http_status_codes.h. Note that this means your response
>   code must match a response code that PHP knows about. You can't create
>   your own response codes using this method, however you can using the
>   header method.
>
> In summary - The differences between `http_response_code` and `header`
>   for setting response codes:
>
> 1. Using `http_response_code` will cause PHP to match and apply a Reason Phrase from a list of Reason Phrases that are hard-coded into
>      the PHP source code.
> 2. Because of point 1 above, if you use `http_response_code` you must set a code that PHP knows about. You can't set your own custom code,
>      however you can set a custom code (and Reason Phrase) if you use the
>      header method.

---

I was curious about how some popular frameworks send the header in a standard response:

[Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L337) (and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses), by inheritance) sets the raw header:

```
// status
header(sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s', $this->version, $this->statusCode, $this->statusText), true, $this->statusCode);
```

[Zend Framework 2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Response.php#L450) also sets the raw header:

```
public function renderStatusLine()
{
    $status = sprintf(
        'HTTP/%s %d %s',
        $this->getVersion(),
        $this->getStatusCode(),
        $this->getReasonPhrase()
    );
    return trim($status);
}
```

And so does [Yii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Response.php#L343)

```
protected function sendHeaders()
{
    if (headers_sent()) {
        return;
    }
    $statusCode = $this->getStatusCode();
    header("HTTP/{$this->version} $statusCode {$this->statusText}");
    // ...
```

Comment: As an additional note, I have encountered a scenario under IIS/FastCGI where `http_response_code` does not work, but you can still set it via `header`.