# Should I define my own HTTP response codes for sending from PHP?

Tags: php, httpresponse

Related: [Best way to send HTTP response code in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433288/best-way-to-send-http-response-code-in-php)

Since I am implementing both client and server sides, I would like to define my own response codes, so are to give meaningful error messages to the user.

The PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) in (currently) comment #48, but Stefan W, says:

> Note that you can NOT set arbitrary response codes with this function,
> only those that are known to PHP (or the SAPI PHP is running on).
>
> The following codes currently work as expected (with PHP running as
> Apache module): 200 – 208, 226 300 – 305, 307, 308 400 – 417, 422 –
> 424, 426, 428 – 429, 431 500 – 508, 510 – 511
>
> Codes 0, 100, 101, and 102 will be sent as "200 OK".
>
> Everything else will result in "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> If you want to send responses with a freestyle status line, you need
> to use the `header()` function:

```
 <?php header("HTTP/1.0 418 I'm A Teapot"); ?>
```

That restricts the number of codes that I can send. Would I better using a generic code and a description error text which the client can present as-is to the user? (or two, one 4xx and one 5xx?)

Are there alternatives? I don't want this question to be closed, but will risk saying that I wax nostalgic for the days when we had a [best-practise](/questions/tagged/best-practise) tag :-(

Comment: I don't think you should start inventing your own HTTP status codes willy-nilly. And I am not sure whether an error message intended for the end user, should be transported this way in the first place.

Comment: _"That restricts the number of codes that I can send. "_ - that applies to `http_response_code`. As the user already mentioned, using `header("HTTP/1.0 ...)` would still allow you to respond with whatever status code you like.

Comment: Obviously it's just an opinion but there's a reason the REST approach to HTTP response codes is popular...

Comment: @CBroe Please remember that I am designing & implementing both server & client. The serve rise in the best position to know exactly what went wrong. If the client sends problematic data due to user input, should I just send a generic response (e.g 409 Conflict; but it doesn't have to be that one). That way the client can only say "invalid user input", and say which field is invalid. The client can't validate, because it is a database problem (already exists), known only to the server - or should I add APIs to verify each user input field individually?

Comment: Cbroe & Adyson, I understand what you both say, which is why this is an exploratory question. It's just that, as I user, I don't like "Microsoft errors", as I refer to them, which generally say "something went wrong" while omitting " - and we know exactly what, but we're not gonna tell you. Nay nya nya nya na!". Can you explain why more precision would be an error if we are 100% certain that only that client will ever use that API?

Comment: _"Please remember that I am designing & implementing both server & client."_ - that doesn't justify "playing fast & lose" with HTTP, in my opinion. (Maybe someone would want to switch out either side of this implementation for a "standard component" later on at some point.) If you need to provide more detailed error information, then why don't do what most APIs do - and put it into the response body? For example as a JSON data structure, that could tell the client what was wrong with which fields in as much details as you like.

Comment: No one will ***ever*** have access to either side of this commercial app. However - and upvote for - "do what most APIs do - and put it into the response body". That's the closest comment yet to answer, so could you please flesh it out (with some code) & post an answer? That's the sort of thing that I was looking for when I asked for alternatives.